# List Is scrolling only in single row

Tags: list, swiftui, enums

I am trying to display a list of enums with a section head.

I am iterating through 2 enums to display them in the same row.

The problem I am having is that the complete list is only showing in one row instead of each individual item displaying on its own row.

Why is this happening?

```
struct DisplayRow: View {

var body: some View {
    List(0..<flaps.allCases.count, id: \.self) {index in
        
            HStack {
                    Text(flaps.allCases[index].rawValue)
                    .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    Text(woundscode.allCases[index].rawValue)
                    }
            .padding(.all)
            .border(Color.gray)
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    List {
        Section(header: Text("Flaps")) {
            DisplayRow()
        }
        Section(header: Text("test")) {
            Text("2")
            Text("3")
        }
    }
```

I placed the 2nd section just as test.

Thanks in advance.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAmIZ.png)

Comment: it's probably due to the height not being correct. Try this as a test: `DisplayRow().frame(height: 333)` in `ContentView`

Comment: If you put List in List then you need to give explicit height for child List otherwise it will be placed just as regular row, because List itself does not have definite height.

Comment: Try using ForEach for the row.